# Как правильно изменить outline при focus через tab

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста как через *CSS* ну или в крайнем случае *JS*, можно реализовать `outline` через **TAB**, но чтобы он не появлялся если зажать на интерактивный элемент и отвести мышку.

```css
.menu__item-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #323232;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.menu__item-link:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<b>Зажмите ссылку и отведите мышку в сторону, outline остается, даже если мы просто нажмем на ссылку, хотя это можно перебить через :active, но после все равно появится аутлайн.</b>
<a class="menu__item-link" href="#"><span>Каталог</span></a>
```

Так вот, как сделать так чтобы рамка появлялась только переключением через **tab**?

Comment: Посмотрите вот это видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHg7DeciuW8 В нем есть информация для вас.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Спасибо, посмотрел, установил полифил.